# git always forces file change

Tags: linux, git, openframeworks

I try to work on the [openFrameworks](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks) repository but am seriously troubled by the behavior of git.

No matter what I do, the file (and only this one) `libs/FreeImage/include/FreeImage.h` is always detected by git as changed.

When I delete the file and execute `git reset libs/FreeImage/include/FreeImage.h` it still is marked as changed (probably line endings!?).

Checking the attributes `git check-attr -a libs/FreeImage/include/FreeImage.h` prints:

```
libs/FreeImage/include/FreeImage.h: text: set
```

The only strange thing about this file I can find is that it has execution rights. I would assume that this comes from some Windows user, who did not disable filemode.

Now, when I go ahead and take the execution rights away and commit the "new" file contents, everything works from there. But, I cannot rebase before the fixing commit, since git ALWAYS forces a file "change".

Could someone explain what is going on?

---

**EDIT:**

There is now an [issue for of](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/2679).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on to something, I have a similar problem from time to time with a couple of files in the OF repo (`Freeimage.h` included, I think).
I was also mystified by the strange and somehow "invisible" file changes (I could never pinpoint exactly what the change *is* with git. Interesting tidbit about the executable bit, that could be it.)

In my personal case, in the end I put it down to using my OF repo via Dropbox both on an ext4-partitioned linux machine, and on another linux machine working off of an ntfs partition with all files mounted as executable.

One thing that always helped in my case to make those mysterious changes go away is a `git stash` followed by a `git stash pop`. After that, my `git status` always became clean. you could try if this remedies the situation for you.

If this is really the executable bit, it would be worthwhile if followed this up with a [bug report](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues) (so that we can at least keep track of it), now that it's clear that this affects more than one user.